# What is the meaning of term "css font stack"? Has the meaning of the term changed?

Tags: css, xhtml, fonts, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver for many years which gives some suggestions to put font-families in CSS.

Is it not a font-stack? What is new in the term "[CSS Font Stack](http://www.codestyle.org/servlets/FontStack)"

What I know is, that one defines multiple font families to keep the typography consistent if any font is not available in system.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the font-family property work in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055865/how-does-the-font-family-property-work-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - You define multiple fonts and the browser will simply choose the first one in the list that you have on your system.

Comment: Ok so basically font stack mean group of multiple font or font-families defined.

Comment: Yep! It is up to you to make sure (on a design perspective) that you choose very similar fonts - but it is entirely up to you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A font stack allows you to define multiple fonts to essentially provide a better experience for users.

Using the CSS `font-family` property, you can define multiple fonts, like so:

`font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;`

This reads from left to right, if the user does not have `Arial` then `font-family` will fallback on `Liberation` all the way down to the most basic `sans-serif` (select any sans-serif font if the aforementioned fonts are not found).

Comment: So will font-size get affected when my font-families changes?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: As long as the aspect ratios of the fonts are not too different. That is to say, `12px` in `Arial` may be not be different at all than `Liberation Sans`. (I'm assuming so, since this is the SO font stack, I think they would have done some testing in this area :) )

Comment: @Russell Dias - Hi Russell thanks for answer. Do you know any method or tool to know the aspect ratios differences between fonts, for fonts which we are defining for same element in CSS.?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: There are quite a few tried and tested web-safe font stacks, a simple Google search will yield plenty. If you want to define your own, maybe a good understanding in Typography might help.

Comment: @Russell Dias - I need a group of similar fonts which should be same in all conditions , font-size in all cases like lowercase, uppercase, Sentense case and with same line-height

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: I answered that in my previous comment.

Comment: @Russell - Yes I know. I was just giving more detail. Although I just found a good tool for my needs. I'm going to play with it http://font-family.com/sandbox#moreSettings

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Glad you found a solution :)

Comment: @Russell - I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555962/css-different-font-sizes-on-different-families There is a CSS3 property to get consistency but not supported well.

Answer (score 0):

font stack, is just a list of fonts (of font families), if the first is not available to the browser, then the second is used etc..

your picture shows 6 font stacks, you could choose from

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing new, this has been the standard way to set fonts for some years now.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your thinking. The pulldown menu has 'Web Safe' font stacks to choose from. If you use any of them your text should render fairly consistently on all devices and on all browsers.

The trend now is to use Google Fonts or some other imported or loaded fonts and thereby control what is rendered. Even then it is recommended to also include one or more alternative standard fonts in a font stack in case your visitors cannot load Google Fonts or the other choices you provide.